# Question with real function and connectedness

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

I asked myself:

If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $f(\mathbb R)$ is connected then does $f$ map connected sets to connected sets?

My idea is that is true: There exists $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $f(\mathbb R)$ connected and a connected set $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ with $f(A)$ **not** conneted.

I try to find an example of this but failed. Now I start to think maybe it is wrong. But I don't know how to think about it. Please can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x$ for $x \ge 0$ and $f(x) = x+1$ for $x < 0$. Then $f(\mathbb R)$ is connected, but $f([-1/10, 1/10])$ is not.

Comment: What would be $f^{-1}[-1/10,1/10]$ for this function? Is it $[0,1/10]\cup [-11/10,-10/10]$?

Comment: Is it possible to find connected $A \subseteq f(\mathbb R)$ with $f^{-1}A$ not connected?

Comment: Yes -- the preimage of $[-1/10, 1/10]$ consists of two pieces, just as you've written. If you draw the graph, this should be pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true in the general case, but it's true for continuous functions (maybe that's why you didn't find a counterexample, sometimes all the functions you think of are continous).

For example, consider $f(x) = \cases{x & $x\leq 0$\\ 1-x & $0<x\leq 1$ \\ x-1 & $1<x$}$

This function is surjective (i.e. $f(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R$), but the image of $(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ is not connected, since it is $(-\frac{1}{2}, 0] \cup (\frac{1}{2}, 1)$.